# Merge two datasets according to cell value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two datasets. One with multiple observations in as shown below:

`Name | Obs 1 | Obs 2 | Obs 3 |                                                                                 AX     0.04    ...      ...                                                                               BX     1.2     ...      ...                                                                                  CX     0.5     ...      ...                                                                               DX     ...     ...      ...                                                                               EX     ...     ...      ...                                                                                  FX     ...     ...      ...                                                                               GX     0.05    ...      ...`

I have a second dataset lets call it x with fewer rows than the dataset above and I would like to create a new column in the above dataset and fill in the values for the appropriate columns while leaving the rest black or with n/a as shown below.

`Name | Obs 1 | Obs 2 | Obs 3 | x |                                                                           AX     0.04    ...      ...   0.02                                                                                                  BX     1.2     ...      ...   n/a                                                                             CX     0.5     ...      ...   n/a                                                                          DX     ...     ...      ...   n/a                                                                          EX     ...     ...      ...   -0.5                                                                           FX     ...     ...      ...   .004                                                                        GX     0.05    ...      ...   n/a`

How do I manage this with Python and Pandas? I imagine Python can search the name column for similarities which is fairly straight forward but I'm not quite sure how to create the appropriate new column.

Comment: 1. Show the second dataset    

2. Describe how the row from the 1st one is related to the row from the 2nd one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge function with a subset of columns you need from the second df :

> df_merged = df_1.merge(df_2[['Name','X']], on='Name')

You can find more detailed help in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html